# Nginx failed to restart after ssl configuration for HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I wanted to serve my website over https and thus I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) exactly as given.

On step 5 `sudo nginx -t` gave positive results as configuration was OK. When I ran `sudo systemctl restart nginx` it gave the following error

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I checked the error logs at /var/log/nginx/error.log if showed this error

> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
>
> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
>
> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
>
> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
>
> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
>
> 2017/03/14 07:35:20 [emerg] 12111#12111: still could not bind()

After tried with tricks like including `ipv6only=on`, apparently nothing seemed to work and now I am clueless what to do?

My default configuration is available [here](http://pastebin.com/n9aNasg4)

Please help

Comment: that looks as if another process opened port tcp/443 and nginx fails to do so because of this. did you check `netstat` for an already opened port 443?

Comment: It looks like openvpn was already using the port 443. Now it's working fine.

Comment: you are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that looks as if another process opened port tcp/443 and nginx fails to do so because of this. did you check netstat for an already opened port 443?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you had this in your config:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

This does the following:

## 1 - I start the server on port 80

Result: OK

## 2 - I start the server on port [::]:80

Result: FAILED

I think with your 2nd line, you are actually calling a listen parameter on both ivp4 and ipv6. Try the following:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
```

See if it works or not.

BTW, you are also missing some very important rows in the config. Namely:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
```